# How to redirect to another page during request in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have regular asp.net page with several buttons on it. I want to have 1 button something like `Stop Request`, so no matter what button were clicked user can click this button and get my page refreshed. So here's example of my idea:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" ToolTip="Click to generate report based on parameters selected above"
                                        Text="Run Report" Width="100px" />
<asp:Button ID="btnCancelRequest" runat="server" Text="Stop Request" OnClientClick="javascript:return CancelRequestClick();"/>
```

So, `btnRefresh` makes a postback that executes SQL Queries and does back-end logic. Let's assume it takes 10-20 seconds for everything to complete. I have few more buttons like this. Some of them executes heavy sql queries and some of them makes some long time execution code on the back. I want to have `btnCancelRequest` button that will just refresh the page, which is will bring clean page back without any user changes.

Here's JS code

```
function CancelRequestClick() {
     window.location.href("RateReport.aspx");
     return false;
};
```

Is there any way to make this JS code to be execute when it clicked and not to wait for response back?

Comment: The question is a little bit hard to understand. When a button is clicked, do you want to execute some command at server-side and come back to UI without wait it to complete? Or you want to cancel something that has been running already at background?

Comment: I want to have ability to cancel all current requests. If user click run button and it executes heave query on the back or user clicks button and it executes any other heave logic on the back I want to have ability to Cancel and refresh page at any time

Answer (score 0):

with javascript, window.stop(), stop the browser loading

```
function CancelRequestClick() {
     window.stop();
     window.location.href("RateReport.aspx");
     return false;
};
```

without javascript, a little bit tricky, submiting a form can cancel the other request, for example a dummy submit to the same page

```
<form action="YourAspxPage.aspx" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="cancel">
</form>
```

pressing cancel will submit dummy form to that page, and stop the other process

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged; please edit your answer to explain why this solves the problem.

Comment: Hi. First of all, I'm working in IE and I found that window.stop; doesn't support by IE. So, I found that I can use document.execCommand("Stop"); insted, but this didn't help. My page still waits till the end of response and then it gets refreshed...

Comment: why cant you just reload page again? attach event on click as you did on refresh "btnRefresh_Click" just create another event for "STOP button" and just reload a page on that click ? like `Response.Redirect("YourAspxPage.aspx");`

Comment: Because if I click btnRefresh first and then btnCancelRequest it will wait till btnRefresh event complete and only then execute btnCancelRequest event.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have ability to cancel all current requests. If user click
>   run button and it executes heave query on the back or user clicks
>   button and it executes any other heave logic on the back I want to
>   have ability to Cancel and refresh page at any time

First of all, HTTP is stateless. It means when a request is served, UI thread is not available anymore. As the result, you do not know that task to cancel.

***What you are hoping to achieve is not possible.*** However, you have a work around. After triggering a long running task, you insert a record in database like -

```
UserId, TaskType, IsCancelled
```

Then let the task to go and check very often about the **IsCancelled** flag.

If you want to cancel it, set IsCancelled flag to true. When the task sees it, it will cancel itself *until then you cannot do anything*.

Ideally, you want to use Scheduler like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) or [Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) for long running jobs, but it is out of the scope of your question.